# Arduino struct does not name a type error

Tags: c++, arduino

In Arduino IDE I can create variables with custom types, but cannot return custom type from function:

This compiles

```
struct Timer
{
  Timer()
  {
  }
};

Timer t;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

This creates `Timer does not name a type` error:

```
struct Timer
{
  Timer()
  {
  }
};

Timer get_timer()
{
  return Timer();
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

Both compile in Orwell Dev-Cpp

I use MEGA-2560

Comment: What's `Timer()` is supposed to denote? A constructor? In a structure? This is not C.

Comment: Yes. A constructor. If I delete it, the issue stays

Comment: Is the first code sample even relevant to your question? And why did you tag this C?

Comment: The first code sample is to illustrate the difference. I may misunderstand c++ and c.

Comment: Well, they're different languages. Maybe the problem is you're trying to compile your code with a C compiler (although the first example shouldn't have compiled either in that case). Anyway, your second example compiles just fine using a C++ compiler.

Comment: Please show us the exact command line options the compiler is using here. Try compiling a trivial program that include some c++ specific keywords to make sure you are indeed compiling with c++. This could perhaps be done with a change to `Timer` to be a `class` with `public` access for everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read [here](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess) about the build process of the Arduino IDE.

Before it can be compiled, your sketch needs to be transformed into a valid C++ file.

Part of this transformation is to create function defitions for all your function declarations.

These definitions are put in the top of the file, before your definition of `Time`. Therefore at the point of declaration of `get_timer`, the type `Time` is not declared yet.

One way to overcome this is to put all your type definitions in a separate `.h` file and include it into your sketch.